# displaying view above sherlock tabs

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

Hi Everyone i am trying to display some view above sherlock tabs. As image shown below[image]

I want to add some view in between the tab and the title bar. Didn't find any solution after searching. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Just for some clarification... above or over the actionbar?